# EF Core performance issue when using dynamic query using Expressions in .Net

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, query-performance

Requirement : Select list of records from table for members whose ID and First name matches with records.
The number of members in the request may vary as per the request:
I have written following code to generate dynamic query using expressions.

```
   private Expression<Func<TmpOncMemberAuth, bool>> CreateQueryExpression(List<MemberRequest> memberRequests)
        {
            var type = typeof(TmpOncMemberAuth);
            // member =>
            var memberParam = Expression.Parameter(type, "member");
            var requests = memberRequests;

            Expression selectLeft = null;
            Expression filterExpression = null;
            foreach (var member in requests)
            {

                var comparison = BuildSubQuery(member, memberParam, type);

                if (selectLeft == null)
                {
                    selectLeft = comparison;
                    filterExpression = selectLeft;
                    continue;
                }

                filterExpression =
                    Expression.Or(filterExpression, comparison);

            }
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TmpOncMemberAuth, bool>>
                (filterExpression, memberParam);

        }

        
        private Expression BuildSubQuery(MemberRequest member, ParameterExpression memberParam, Type type)
        {
            // LHS
            // member.MemberID
            Expression leftMemberID = Expression.Property(memberParam, type.GetProperty("MemberId"));
            Expression leftMemberFirstName = Expression.Property(memberParam, type.GetProperty("MemberFirstName"));
           
           
            // RHS
            Expression requestMemberID = Expression.Constant(member.MemberID);
            Expression requestFirstName = Expression.Constant(member.FirstName);
           
            // member.MemberID == requestMemberID
            Expression compareID =
                Expression.Equal(leftMemberID, requestMemberID);

            Expression compareFName =
                Expression.Equal(leftMemberFirstName, requestFirstName);          

            // condition for a member
            Expression comparison = Expression.AndAlso(compareID, compareFName);
           
            return comparison;
        }

// query call in the main
  var whereQuery = CreateQueryExpression(memberData);

  var memberAuthData = await FindAllAsyncFromTemp(whereQuery);
```

This generate a SQL query in the below format, which take a lot time

```
SELECT [#].[CaseID] AS [CaseId], [#].[MemberID] AS [MemberId], [#].[MemberFirstName], [#].[MemberLastName], [#].[MemberDOB] 
FROM [#ONCMemberAuth] AS [#]
WHERE ((CASE
    WHEN (([#].[MemberID] = '12345') AND ([#].[MemberFirstName] = 'James') ) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END | CASE
    WHEN (([#].[MemberID] = '6789') AND ([#].[MemberFirstName] = 'WILLERS') ) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END) 
    ) = CAST(1 AS bit)
```

I need to create SQL query like below which executes faster than the above one

```
SELECT [#].[CaseID] AS [CaseId], [#].[MemberID] AS [MemberId], [#].[MemberFirstName], [#].[MemberLastName], [#].[MemberDOB] 
FROM [#ONCMemberAuth] AS [#]
WHERE ((([#].[MemberID] = '1234') AND ([#].[MemberFirstName] = 'James')) OR (([#].[MemberID] = '56789') AND ([#].[MemberFirstName] = 'WILLERS') ) )
```

Comment: Change `Expression.Or` to `Expression.OrElse`.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I see you do not need more reputation :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks Ivan, that was brutally simple! I see lot difference in performance.